# Set recordtype for Account using DeveloperName

Tags: apex, soql

Is it possible to set recordType for e.g. Account using DeveloperName or we need to SOQL recordtypeID from recordTypes?

Comment: Describe calls for record type has methods that'll return record type id based on account and record type developer name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can avoid using a query by using SObject describe information ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm#apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo)).

`Id targetRectypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('my_recordtype_name').getRecordTypeId();`

Comment: There's also `getRecordTypeInfosByName()`, which gives you a map keyed on the UI label of the record type. Basically, ByName would use "my recordtype name" whereas ByDeveloperName would use "my_recordtype_name".

Comment: I used this answer recently and found that it needs to be "Schema.SObjectType..." now.